# How to delete empty duplicates in a dataframe in a smart way?

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, dataset, data-cleaning

I have a large dataset. It has some data missing. Dataset contains variables of types `string` (for columns such as name) and `float` (for columns such as height). Some rows in this dataset are just duplicates (sometimes with a suffix number) that are missing data. What i want to do is to delete the empty duplicates, leave the ones that have data (sometimes the same person can have 2 rows filled with different data, but that's okay and i want to leave it like that).

An important thing to know is that while I changed empty values in string type columns to `np.nan`, in `float` type columns empty vals are represented by `-99.0`. By the way, is it better to set it as `-1` instead of `-99.0`? or there's no difference? I'm later going to use it in machine a learning model.

So my solution would be to:

1. Write a function that given two row indices returns the index of the one that has more data in it, if they both are filled with data, returns both.
2. Write another function that would iterate through the dataset and (using the previous function) compare the duplicates and delete the empty ones.

But the thing is, it would require quite a lot of coding for me and it doesn't seem really smart way to do this (i know there probably is a better way). Not to mention the horrendous bugs i ran into while trying to do it my way...

Anyways, do you guys know a better way to do this? Doesn't even have to necessarily be code, just an idea how to do it more efficiently. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to drop columns with empty "NaN" values then run this

```
df.dropna(subset = ["column_with_empty_NaNs"], inplace=True)
```

If you want to drop a row with any empty cells

```
df.dropna(axis=0, how='any', thresh=None, subset=None, inplace=False)
```

If you want to drop a row with all empty cells

```
df.dropna(axis=0, how='all', thresh=None, subset=None, inplace=False)
```

Comment: Link to reference for the `dropna()` function: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html#pandas.DataFrame.dropna